# Ext4 - Last write time

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, ext4

I'm currently looking at an issue with data loss and was using the `tune2fs` utility, and I was wondering what 'Last write time:' refers to. The volume is written to constantly and backups confirm that the data that I lost has been backed up, but I just want to understand what that field means as it can't be the last time data was written to disk (there are files on the disk with newer creation times than the last write time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “Last write time” in `tune2fs`’ output reflects the last time the super block was written. This doesn’t change when files are written to the device, only when certain pieces of information stored in the super block change — in particular, when the devices is mounted, or when its recovery status changes, or when an error is encountered.

Comment: What "last write time" actually means seems subject to much debate. Because one time it should most definitely indicate it was re-written is before an orderly shutdown, and that's not happening.

Comment: In case you want to change the "Last write time", you can run `e2label /dev/sda1 "name of volume"`. A bit like `touch`, but for volumes.